# React - Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the key props in a React JS component.

I'm getting

*Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of Login. It was passed a child from App.*

warning in console log. App component is as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../common/header';
import HeaderCompact from '../common/headerCompact';
import Footer from '../common/footer';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lang: 1
    };
  }

  changeLang(name, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch (name) {
      case "fra" :
        this.setState({lang: 2});
        break;
      case "ger" :
        this.setState({lang: 3});
        break;
      case "ned" :
        this.setState({lang: 4});
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({lang: 1});
    }
  }


  render() {
    let currentRoute = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);
    let header = currentRoute === "" ? <Header onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/> :
      <HeaderCompact currentRoute={currentRoute} onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/>;
    return (
      <div>
        {header}
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {lang: this.state.lang})}
        <Footer lang={this.state.lang}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my login component is as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './loginForm';

const Login = ({currentLanguage}) => {

    const language = currentLanguage;

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <p className="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 loginTitle noPadding">{language.loginTitle}</p>
                <div className="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-md-8 loginForm noPadding">
                    <LoginForm currentLanguage={language}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

I'm still new in React and I'm not sure what should I pass like a key and where?

**UPDATE**

LoginForm component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

import TextInput from '../../common/formElements/textInput';
import LoginButton from '../../common/formElements/button';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            loginData: {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            errors: {}
        };

        this.buttonClickHandle = this.buttonClickHandle.bind(this);
        this.loginHandle = this.loginHandle.bind(this);
    }

    loginHandle(event) {
        let field = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;
        this.state.loginData[field] = value;
        return this.setState({loginData: this.state.loginData});
    }

    buttonClickHandle(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("It's clicked/n");
    }

    render() {
        const language = this.props.currentLanguage;

        return (
            <div className="contact_form">
                <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 smScrPdLeft" style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                        <TextInput
                            type="text"
                            name="username"
                            label=""
                            placeholder={language.loginUsername}
                            className="templateInput loginUsername col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
                            id="name"
                            sizeClass=""
                            onChange={this.loginHandle}
                            value={this.state.username}
                            errors={this.state.errors.username}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 smPadding" style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                        <TextInput
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            label=""
                            placeholder={language.loginPassword}
                            className="templateInput loginPassword col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
                            id="password"
                            sizeClass=""
                            onChange={this.loginHandle}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            errors={this.state.errors.password}
                        />
                        <Link to="/" className="forgotPassLabel">{language.forgotPassword}</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 btnLogin noPadding smScrPdRight" style={{marginTop: 4}}>
                        <LoginButton onClick={() => this.buttonClickHandle(event)} name="registration" value={language.loginBtnText} className="rightFloat" icon="user"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Routes file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

HomePage Component

```
return (
    <div>
        <div className="sidebar-menu-container" id="sidebar-menu-container">

            <div className="sidebar-menu-push">

                <div className="sidebar-menu-overlay"></div>

                <div className="sidebar-menu-inner">

                    <section className="marginOnXs" style={{width: '100%', padding: 0}}>
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row hideOnXS">
                                <MainSlider />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </section>

                    <div id="cta-1" className="onlyOnDesktop">
                        <Login currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                    </div>

                    <section className="why-us" style={{paddingTop: 0}}>
                        <Info currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                    </section>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>

                    <section className="featured-listing">
                        <CarsList allCars={carsList()} currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                    </section>

                    <section className="contactSection">
                        <ContactForm currentLanguage={languageHome}/>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Probably a silly question but: Did you remember to import your components? I got the very same message when I had <MyComonent />  inside a component, where MyComponent wasn't imported..

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/50551566#50551566

Comment: I've edited your question. In the future with react questions please also include the `javascript` tag: for some reason SO's syntax highlighting won't work if you don't. Someone asked a question on meta about it 3 years ago, but apparently it died for want of attention.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know how your `LoginForm` component looks like.

But each time you iterate over an array you have to set the `key` prop to each of the resulting `DOM` element as `React` needs it to optimize the re-rendering.
For example:

```
<div className="container">
        {myarray.map((element, index) => {
            return <div key={'mykey' + index}>{element}</div>;
        })}
</div>
```

`React` for example will detect duplicates and only renders the first `node` with this `key`.

Comment: I updated my question. But I'm not iterating an array anywhere, I do not have map anywhere.

Comment: hm. What exactly is passed with `this.props.children` in your `App` component? Maybe this is an array? Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: I updated the code for the App component. The state is passed; that is only a number.

Comment: No I mean the children that are passed to your `App` component. >> `<App>{//the children you are passing here}</App>`. This is the place where an array could be passed. See description at the top at https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html

Comment: The App component is called from routes file, from React Router. I updated my question with that file.

Comment: Oh man. I have no idea. Everything you posted looks good to me. The only component I did not see yet is `HomePage`. Guess for further inspection a running fiddle is needed. - Sorry

Comment: It's really strange. I updated my question with HomePage component. And thanks ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113894/discussion-between-richard-rutsche-and-boky).

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this warning is that **you have not passed 'key' property**. React uses this property for optimizing the rendering process as in when something changes in React, a re-render will occur only for what all has changed.

If our children are dynamic and in case they get shuffled with random functions or new components are introduced in the beginning of an array, the re-render is likely to get messed up. So, **assigning this 'key' property helps us make sure that the state and identity of our components is maintained through multiple renders**.
Please find below a sample code snippet demonstrating how to pass a key.

```
<MyComponent key={{item.key}}/>
```

The importance of key is beautifully explained [here](https://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/).

Comment: While certainly correct this answer would be improved by the addition of a code example.

Comment: Thanks, @JaredSmith! Edited my answer.

Comment: I certainly appreciate you updating your answer, but please actually post the code *in* your answer: links can and do go dead. If the code example is one that you got from somewhere else as opposed to created yourself, by all means add the link for attribution but still post the code inside your actual answer.

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith for your feedback. Please correct me if you think I am still missing on anything.