# lodash react router eventKey

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, lodash

I am trying to create a set of Links using lodash so they can be changed easily.

```
  {_.map(leftItems, item => (
    <Menu.Item>
      <Link {...item} eventKey={{ ...item.eventkey }} />{' '}
    </Menu.Item>
      ))}
```

And I am then bringing the items in with this JSON

```
const leftItems = [
  {
    content: 'Component1',
    key: 'component1',
    eventkey: 1,
    to: '/component1',
    className: 'left'
  },
  {
    content: 'Component2',
    key: 'component2',
    eventkey: 2,
    to: '/component2',
    className: 'left'
  },
  {
    content: 'Component3',
    key: 'component3',
    eventkey: 3,
    to: '/component3',
    className: 'left'
  },
  {
    content: 'Component4',
    key: 'component4',
    eventkey: 4,
    to: '/component4',
    className: 'left'
  }
];
```

I am having issues getting rid of either of these errors:

index.js:2178 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

index.js:2178 Warning: React does not recognize the `eventKey` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `eventkey` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: I have tried this as well: key={item.eventkey} and still get that it isn't a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the unique key on `<Menu.Item>`, i.e.:

```
{_.map(leftItems, item => (
    <Menu.Item key={item.eventkey}>
      <Link {...item} />{' '}
    </Menu.Item>
))}
```

`eventKey={{ ...item.eventkey }}` is unnecessary as it is implied by your spread operator `{...item}`

Comment: Just solved it as you typed it.  Thanks for the help :) <Menu.Item key={item.key}>
              <Link {...item}>{item.content}</Link>
            </Menu.Item>

Comment: If anyone else faces this issue please see this post for more help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651660/react-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop