# React: Getting runtime error/warning in browser when a component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create the [left hand menu like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFV43.png) for my test application using react, and I am getting the following warning/error at runtime on the browser console when loaded.

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `LeftNav`. See fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

in Fragment (at LeftNav.js:12)
in LeftNav (at App.js:131)
in div (at App.js:120)
in div (at App.js:118)
in div (at App.js:116)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:115)
in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

Each of the navItems props items have distinct IDs, so every component should already have unique keys?
Should the React.Fragment have a unique key as well?
The LeftNav component is as below

```
class LeftNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.navItems.map((navItem) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <LeftNavItem key={navItem.id} navItem={navItem} menuLevel={0} />
                            {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
                                return <LeftNavItem key={subMenuItem.id} navItem={subMenuItem} menuLevel={1} />
                            })}

                        </React.Fragment>
                    )

                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

LeftNav.propTypes = {
    navItems: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default LeftNav;
```

LeftNavItem component is as below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class LeftNavItem extends Component {
    getClassName = () => {
        if(this.props.menuLevel === 0) {
            return 'parent_wrapper';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li className={this.getClassName()}>
                <a href="">{this.props.navItem.title}</a>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

LeftNavItem.propTypes = {
    navItem: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default LeftNavItem;
```

The props for LeftNav class is

```
leftNav: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'System Admin',
    active: false,
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: '',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: '',
        active: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    title: 'Reports',
    active: false,
    subMenu: [
      {
        id: 11,
        title: 'Reports',
        active: false
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        title: 'Dashboard',
        active: true
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        title: 'Templates',
        active: false
      }
    ]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651660/react-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)

Comment: you need to provide key to `<React.Fragment>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your key to the fragment instead of the nested tag.

```
return (
       <React.Fragment key={navItem.id}>
            <LeftNavItem navItem={navItem} menuLevel={0} />
            {navItem.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => {
                return <LeftNavItem key={subMenuItem.id} navItem={subMenuItem} menuLevel={1} />
            })}

       </React.Fragment>
)
```